# What's a proper way of type-punning a float to an int and vice-versa?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, gcc-warning, strict-aliasing, type-punning

The code below performs a fast inverse square root operation by some bit hacks.
The algorithm was probably developed by Silicon Graphics in early 1990's and it's appeared in Quake 3 too.
[more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

However I get the following **warning from GCC C++ compiler**: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break *strict-aliasing* rules

Should I use `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead in such situations?

```
float InverseSquareRoot(float x)
{
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    int32_t i = *(int32_t*)&x;
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = *(float*)&i;
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: The paper gives the value 0x5fe6ec85e7de30da as the optimal constant for doubles in the conclusion.

Comment: "Lomont pointed out that the "magic number" for 64 bit IEEE754 size type double is 0x5fe6ec85e7de30da, but in fact it was shown to be exactly 0x5fe6eb50c7b537a9" (from Wikipedia) Maybe I'll do some tests.

Comment: Oh interesting. I didn't know about McEniry's paper. Thanks :)

Comment: This trick is completely free of undefined behavior, assuming the float and int bits are compatible to each other: `union A { float x; int32_t y; }; int32_t value = A{3.14f}.y;` the reason is, that the aliasing rule is never applied here. However, this trick only works up to C++11 (I think C++14 will change the rules so that this becomes UB).

Comment: Your `pseudo_cast` in C++ should also `static_assert` that both types are trivially copiable (see `std::is_trivially_copyable`).

Comment: Near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67636231/5740428

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Forget casts. Use `memcpy`.

```
float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
uint32_t i;
assert(sizeof(x) == sizeof(i));
std::memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof(i));
i = 0x5f375a86 - (i>>1);
std::memcpy(&x, &i, sizeof(i));
x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
return x;
```

The original code tries to initialize the `int32_t` by first accessing the `float` object through an `int32_t` pointer, which is where the rules are broken. The C-style cast is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`, so changing it to `reinterpret_cast` would not make much difference.

The important difference when using memcpy is that the bytes are copied from the `float` into the `int32_t`, but the `float` object is never accessed through an `int32_t` lvalue, because `memcpy` takes pointers to void and its insides are "magical" and don't break the aliasing rules.

Comment: Yeah, is it faster too, or just because of the clarity?

Comment: @plasmacel: No. It's obviously slower. But it is actually defined.

Comment: @Jan Why is it “obviously” slower? I don’t find that obvious at all.

Comment: @plasmacel Mostly because it works. I wouldn't expect any discernible difference in performance from a reasonable compiler. (Yes, I am sure MSVC will prove me wrong...)

Comment: It's only slower if the compiler does a horrible job of optimizing it. [Here's proof that gcc 4.8 compiles the cast and memcpy version to the same assembly.](http://goo.gl/atXuLe) [And unknown version of clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=11c2a965452fccaf7f7f2816953750fb-718da30730c3c592fdabec0dec6148ca).

Comment: @Casey For some definition of "horrible".  It requires some special handling in the compiler to optimize this, and a C++ compiler is probably in the right to consider that calls to `memcpy` are so rare that they don't matter, and to not bother.  (Of course, most C++ compilers share some parts with C, where it _does_ matter.)

Comment: The only question that the original code was right in C? Or why is it implemented (by Silicon Graphics, Quake 3, etc...) in such way?

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, "horrible" is hyperbole. Nevertheless, I'd expect a current mainstream compiler to optimize the memcpy to a register copy.

Comment: @Casey just for completeness, the clang running on Coliru is a 3.4 trunk build (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-31da585d534e2dd05f4f3fdc81c22629)

Comment: @plasmacel The original code has been illegal in C for the same reason since C99.

Comment: @plasmacel: If memory serves, that code would have been valid C (and probably C++ too) when it was written in the early 1990s. I don't think the aliasing rules existed before C++98 and C99.

Comment: I fear that my "proof that it compiles to the same assembly" comment above will be construed by someone to indicate that it's reasonable to write code that breaks the aliasing rules. Realize that this is relying on undefined behavior, and just as in any other case of undefined behavior it may produce different results with different compilers, or different compiler versions, or on Tuesday instead of Monday, .... etc. *The most dangerous possible outcome of undefined behavior is to do what you expect during testing.*

Comment: @MikeSeymour, C89 said, "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue that has one of the following types: the declared type of the object, a qualified version of the declared type of the object, [signed or unsigned variants], an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members [], or a character type" in 6.3 Expressions. That's basically the same as the C99 wording and bans the original code.

Comment: You should use uint32_t for this, although I think a signed overflow is impossible with this code.

Comment: How is `memcpy` "magical"? Where is it specified? It must be implemented somehow, right?

Comment: @rustyx it's magical in the sense that it is a primitive that doesn't behave in the same way a user implementation would. By treating it as a primitive, the compiler can do all sorts of magical things with it as e.g. in Casey's code above. It doesn't really have to be implemented; in fact in many compilers it is a compiler intrinsic; attempts at implementing it yourself are likely to end up turned into the intrinsic itself, e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56888

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Unfortunately, if the destination of `memcpy` doesn't have a declared type, compilers are allowed to "magically" fail to update objects whose effective type doesn't match the source, and which will next be used as that other type.

Answer (score 14):

There are a few good answers here that address the type-punning issue.

I want to address the "fast inverse square-root" part.  Don't use this "trick" on modern processors.  Every mainstream vector ISA has a dedicated hardware instruction to give you a fast inverse square-root.  Every one of them is both faster and more accurate than this oft-copied little hack.

These instructions are all available via intrinsics, so they are relatively easy to use.  In SSE, you want to use `rsqrtss` (intrinsic: `_mm_rsqrt_ss( )`); in NEON you want to use `vrsqrte` (intrinsic: `vrsqrte_f32( )`); and in AltiVec you want to use `frsqrte`.  Most GPU ISAs have similar instructions.  These estimates can be refined using the same Newton iteration, and NEON even has the `vrsqrts` instruction to do part of the refinement in a single instruction without needing to load constants.

Answer (score 9):

If you have access to C++20 or later then you can use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

```cpp
float InverseSquareRoot(float x)
{
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    int32_t i = std::bit_cast<int32_t>(x);
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = std::bit_cast<float>(i);
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x;
}
```

At the moment, `std::bit_cast` is [supported by all major compilers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20). See [demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwCcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgABykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJrtuyDP4gmfYJhoAgnsHR5in5zGEt/dPj1S0qCYBGOAEkGAA3eJKIQARy8TUwACVUKgCNQAUDjqplj8TAB2KyPY7E47/QHA1QIMRUd4AEWOGgAdABWKgAKlUZ0JDxJx3CBF2ZgA%2BsC8HTjlcQCBPgQhaIZmc3PzBSLbhBsVyfryxWd6RpVKzdnjmQF0DSALTHCB4b67bBcHG7bm81TiyXSwhypgK85koFqvCO50k126rFsiBcFkWrFU2js1QcoNaknETAEDYMLGax742k/DirWicZm8PwcLSkVCcNzWawS9abN57HikAiaQurADWEjxjI0iQ0u12AQAbJI8WZEgFdsy8fpOJIyx2q5xeAoQBo2x3VnBYEg0CwUnR4uRKIfj/QEuDkCkUkLwVwAkKzHihapx6QsOC8FsAGp4JgADuADyKSMJwrY0LQBBQpQMQrp8zDEAAnpBvBIU0KEgTE2i1O23C8IebCCCBDC0GhFa8FgMReMAbhiLQG6EV%2BmAsIYwDiFRX54GmdSQsxlaYKotReLB6HkIIXQSbQeAxMQWEeFgEkEMQeAsOhqz/EwwAKABwFgRBLH8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOo3G6Fw%2BgcSgdaWPockbpAqyoCkPTMQA9JKpiWNYBiwTMxz%2BSBZi8KgkLEGpWCeRAqw1HUzgQK4kx%2BI5oTzOUlR6IUmQCNlRXpCVDCDAVIyOWlPR9BMnhtHo9X1LM1XDAkdWzGVPX9J1izdaljZbBIRYlsu3HVhwWLjscLAKDexyPgEjKvlauCECQpxmLsDq8ARWjLN2/hMpIZgaHiiRmKOo5GhokgBI5xYcEupDlpWM3rpu25UbuMCICgqBHieZAUBAF5gyAwBcHtrE/v%2BgGgeB5ZQXQsHEBuEAIdxmGoRJ%2BPYbh%2BEScRjAEGRFErjRdEMbQTESVg7FGFxlb4HxjgCSuwmieJLH8tJLGyfJikYNsraqepml8AYun6SjRlQbIZniJZJnyEoagrroZhOUYLkhW5IvJd5vlZMx5pXLqwVWJYl2xfFiWYKbnTdFkLgMO4zV5LlXuDYVjnFT0fWpBVPQB7Vbv4e1/Sh21AiNXMZRda1vU%2BzlYwDflqcOmsGxjXnr2lh9K4zViiSjua83AMgyDHHDjK7Jt%2BBEMQu37csh07qdRqMk9iSJHieKjtOGgaHO0ive9n2xWuti/UdhakHuQNQ1eZ6QyDl4jIcHFcKO48I7%2BmAK4ZaO8NBmPY7jlZE4T4RYTheEOGTIMkZT5GUezmC0fRjHMVbMzDibNqK8RjtzbivNkBiQlrwQWr1WwiwUqhJScC2xqQ0oRLScs9LI3PhJDWqsLLSA1jZbW9kQC7H1sYVyNgTbwDNn5TgVsCDoBtnQh2VYnZ4CSow6O6U/CZS9qHPKKchrlSKFkUOwcsiR26gIhq6dciZwTr0DqOcJH9SaiotO2dxGBxGgXCyE0OAl1nquWaqhK7V0kMcPeRgG6jn7P2Fu2124ti7n9Y6p0zDMgXG9KaX154bi3EvE6ASYql2mvPcJqx4oZGcJIIAA%3D%3D%3D)

If you're using an old version of Clang you can try [`__builtin_bit_cast`](https://reviews.llvm.org/D62825). Just change the casts like this

```cpp
int32_t i = __builtin_bit_cast(std::int32_t, x);
x = __builtin_bit_cast(float, i);
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Cbit%3E%0A%0Afloat+InverseSquareRoot(float+x)%0A%7B%0A++++float+xhalf+%3D+0.5f*x%3B%0A++++int32_t+i+%3D+__builtin_bit_cast(std::int32_t,+x)%3B%0A++++i+%3D+0x5f3759df+-+(i%3E%3E1)%3B%0A++++x+%3D+__builtin_bit_cast(float,+i)%3B%0A++++x+%3D+x*(1.5f+-+xhalf*x*x)%3B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.09993468321359,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1100,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+11.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:62.90006531678641,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

**I no longer believe this answer is correc**t, due to feedback I've gotten from the committee.  But I want to leave it up for informational purposes.  And I am purposefully hopeful that this answer can be made correct by the committee (if it chooses to do so).  I.e. there's nothing about the underlying hardware that makes this answer incorrect, it is just the judgement of a committee that makes it so, or not so.

---

I'm adding an answer not to refute the accepted answer, but to augment it.  I believe the accepted answer is both correct and efficient (and I've just upvoted it).  However I wanted to demonstrate another technique that is just as correct and efficient:

```
float InverseSquareRoot(float x)
{
    union
    {
        float as_float;
        int32_t as_int;
    };
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    as_float = x;
    as_int = 0x5f3759df - (as_int>>1);
    as_float = as_float*(1.5f - xhalf*as_float*as_float);
    return as_float;
}
```

Using clang++ with optimization at -O3, I compiled plasmacel's code, R. Martinho Fernandes code, and this code, and compared the assembly line by line.  All three were identical. **This is due to the compiler's choice to compile it like this. It had been equally valid for the compiler to produce different, broken code.**

Comment: First of all, the proposed solution is the same as in doron's answer, although you spell it out in code. But secondly, does this mean that the way we interpret the rules for unions these days means they can be used for type punning after all? There used to be a rule that you cannot set one member and then read another. See here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined

Comment: @jogojapan:  Good comment.  I thought it important to show code.  English can be so vague and ambiguous.  On your second point, I'm glad you brought it up.  I think the C++ committee needs to address this issue and recommend safe techniques for type punning.  There have been discussions in the Library Working Group specifically requesting direction from the Core or Evolution Working Group on how this should best be accomplished.  These questions, to the best of my knowledge, have so far gone unanswered. However, my belief at this time is that compiler writers will not violate the C99 contract.

Comment: Alright then... +1 for the time being :) (I'd suggest incorporating the comment in the answer, though.)

Comment: As far as I'm aware `memcpy` is _the_ recommended approach for type punning in C++. C++ compilers may maintain the C99 union guarantee, however it's still undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: @jogojapan I have summarized how I understand the current rules here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17819398/34509

Comment: For up to C++11, you can use my above union trick to be free of aliasing issues: `union A { float x; int32_t y; }; int32_t value = A{3.14f}.y;` (I don't really think that this is anymore safer than doing it without the temporary :D). The reason this "works" is that the initializer is a prvalue and hence is free of the aliasing rule restrictions. This however will change in C++14 because the initializer will be an xvalue :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't believe the strict aliasing rules are the only restriction on type punning with unions in C++. For example I believe your example runs afoul of _8.5 [dcl.init]/16_ where it says "the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression." since the object designated by `A{3.14f}.y` does not have any value. C++ omits specification of behavior in this situation and so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @bames53 why is the object designated not the float object previously initialized?

Comment: @bames53 I agree that the rules need clarification though. I suspect the way to read this as being UB is that the access using another member does not alias the lvalue with the object currently being alive, but with a distinct nonalive object associated with the other member. That needs the concept of a "nonclass type object of type T that is not alive but existing". From previous runs through the spec, I couldn't make sense of that. Perhaps i failed. Or the solution is that it simply refers to no object at all.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb As I read it, the int32_t member is designated because it's the one named, that object is distinct from the float member object, and as far as I can tell none of the cases where using one object's name ends up referring to a different object (e.g., 3.8/7) apply so the name `y` doesn't refer to the `x` object currently using `y`'s storage. The spec definitely leaves something to be desired in defining the lifetime of union members.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb And by 'C99 guarantee' I mean the guarantee that reading a non-active member will reinterpret the stored representation of the active member. In C11 they added an explicit note to that effect, but I haven't looked at the C spec enough to know if the normative language of the C99 spec truly does imply what the C11 note claims.

Comment: Howard, I notice that 9.5 says about unions "Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a
struct." but "A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. ]"  Should the second rule read *standard-layout class* and not *standard-layout struct*?

Comment: The second quote is 9.2/19

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Just to clarify: When I said "rule" in my comment above, I didn't mean an explicit statement in the Standard. I meant a general rule that C++ programmers are expected to comply with, on the basis of an _interpretation_ of the explicit rules of the Standard. My assumption that there is a rule of "don't set one member and then read another" for unions was based (among other things) on the interpretation given by ecatmur in the question you link to.

Comment: @barnes53 "In C11 they added an explicit note to that effect" - it's also in C99 as of Technical Corregendum 3 (published in 2007).

Comment: Why this answer is wrong is explained very clearly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior/11996970#11996970).

Comment: `clang++` is an implementation of the *GNU* dialect of C++, where the behaviour of union type-punning *is* guaranteed, same as C99.  ([Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848)).  I doubt ISO C++ will ever define the behaviour, even for trivially-copyable types, but the comittee finally got around to providing a nice way to type-pun: C++20 [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

Answer (score 1):

The cast invokes undefined behaviour. No matter what form of cast you use, it will still be undefined behaviour. It is undefined no matter what type of cast you use.

Most compilers will do what you expect, but gcc likes being mean and is probably going to assume you didn't assign the pointers despite all indication you did and reorder the operation so they give some strange result.

Casting a pointer to incompatible type and dereferencing it is an undefined behaviour. The only exception is casting it to or from char, so the only workaround is using `std::memcpy` (as per R. Martinho Fernandes' answer). (I am not sure how much it is defined using unions; It does stand a better chance of working though).

That said, you should not use C-style cast in C++. In this case, `static_cast` would not compile, nor would `dynamic_cast`, forcing you to use `reinterpret_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` is a strong suggestion you might be violating strict aliasing rules.

Comment: There are different reasons for undefined behavior.  In this case, of course, there's no way the standards committee could define it, particularly in the face of possible trapping representations for `float` (usual) or `int` (rare, but can exist).  On the other hand, the intend is clearly that it should have the behavior which someone familiar with the architecture would expect.  A compiler which breaks this, _when the cast is immediately visible_, is simply broken.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes He's casting pointers, not `float` nor `int`, and `static_cast` won't convert between arbitrary pointers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The reason for the undefined behaviour is that the specification _explicitely undefines it_.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Compiler that breaks this when the cast is immediately visible is conforming to the specification. Gcc does just that (in fact I think it won't break it as written, because the int pointer is cast back, but it would almost certainly read the original value back from the original variable, because it deleted the dependency and would consider the value left in floating pointer register valid.)

Comment: @JanHudec That's circular reasoning.  The standards committee didn't decide to make it undefined because the standard says it is undefined; they had specific motives.  And other language in the same section makes it clear that the intent was for the behavior to be "unsurprising" for someone familiar with the architecture of the machine.

Comment: @JanHudec A compiler which ignores aliases due to a `reinterpret_cast` in the immediate block is broken.  It may be conform to the letter of the standard, but it clearly violates the intent.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Better to break right away in ALL situations rather than work sometimes and not others. If you move the cast out of the function and it silently breaks would you be happy?

Comment: ...all of which makes this a case where the compiler should "do the right thing" with the code when it can, and throw up red flags all over the place to warn you that you are teetering on the edge. Remember that the standard's requirement that the compiler diagnose nonconforming code doesn't preclude the compiler from producing a working program.

Comment: @Casey Good point.  A warning when you pass a cast pointer to a function would definitely be in order.

Comment: @ZanLynx In other words, you're saying that the compiler should break aliasing with `union` as well.  The situation is basically the same: historically, both casting and unions were used for type punning.  For whatever reasons, the C committee decided to bless casting (although only via intent, because you cannot define the behavior), but a good compiler will support both, in the same situations.  (And of course, the technique with `memcpy` is just as much undefined behavior as the others, for the same reasons.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: No, the `memcpy` technique is defined. The exact values are implementation defined, but they must be the value represented by the same sequence of bytes in memory. On the other hand type punning is undefined and the compiler may do anything it pleases. For union I don't remember the specification exactly, but the rules are basically similar.

Comment: @JanHudec The behavior using `memcpy` is only defined if you copy back into the original type.  The same concerns as for `reinterpret_cast` are involved: the standard cannot define the results of copying the bit pattern of an `int` into a `float` (even if the two types have the same size), since it does not want to constrain the implementation.  On the machines I know, for example, copying an `int` into a `float`, then accessing the `float`, may cause the process to abort (if the bits in the `int` correspond to a trapping `NaN`, for example).

Comment: @JamesKanze: No. You are mixing two _very different undefineds_. The behaviour of reinterpret cast is "Undefined". That means the compiler is free to do anything ranging from what you expect to formatting your harddrive and making daemons flying from your nose. But the memcpy behaviour is "Implementation Defined". The specification says the implementation must copy the actual bytes and only does not say what the value represented by the same bits shall mean. Yes, it may cause fault if the value is a signalling NaN, but it may *not* involve any daemons. And must be deterministic.

Comment: @JanHudec Behavior of the `reinterpret_cast` is implementation defined.  (In C++11, it's fully defined if the types are standard layout types, as they are here.)  The issue is accessing something as a `float`, when it hasn't been initialized as a `float`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Accessing something as `float` when it hasn't been _initialized_ as `float` is _also implementation defined_. The thing that is undefined is accessing the same memory location as two incompatible types neither of which is char (so called aliasing rules). The char exception allows you to initialize something not as float (via `memcpy` or other standard library functions taking buffer) and access it as, say, float and still be (implementation) defined.

Comment: @JanHudec Accessing something as a `float` which wasn't initialized as a `float` is undefined behavior.  (Of course, an implementation may choose to define it, but it isn't required to.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/) for more information on type punning and strict aliasing.

The only safe cast of a type into an array is into a `char` array. If you want one data address to be switchable to different types you will need to use a `union`

Comment: Using a union for type punning doesn't conform with the Standard either (although it typically works).

Comment: @jogojapan - strictly speaking type-punning unions do violate the strict aliasing rule and are not defined but they are a common enough idiom for GCC to support them (and no generated the warning)

Comment: The strict aliasing rule doesn't mention them (at least not explicitly). But the rules for unions state that you must only read from the member of the union that was last set. For type punning you have to write one member and then read another.

Comment: @jogojapan 3.10/10 does explicitly mention unions in bullet 6. Accessing the value stored in an object through a glvalue whose type is a union containing the dynamic type of the object as a member is defined behavior. You may violate the "last member set" rule, but it does not violate aliasing. </nitpick>

Comment: @Casey So it mentions unions after all. But that still supports what I said.

Comment: @Casey and All, my claim about the rules for unions might have to be revised in light of [Howard Hinnant's answer and comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17799428/777186). +1 for bringing up unions first.

Comment: The linked article says that using union not only is also undefined behaviour, but that it actually is getting optimized to nonsense by at least one compiler.

Comment: @jogojapan there is no such rule that forbids reading another member, for unions.

Comment: I've opened a query about this on the Core Working Group mailing list.

Comment: @Casey that rule is intended for this case `Object *o = ...; int *p = &o->i; f(o, p);`, such that when the function `f` changes `param1->i = 10;`, it cannot cache `*param2` and must rearead from memory. I'm pretty sure to apply it to union or struct members like you did (do you wanna read a `struct A { float y; int x; }` by an `int` lvalue?) is a misapplication.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb No, I want to read a `float` or `int` through a `union {float f; int i;}` lvalue, which 3.10/10 ("the aliasing rule") does not describe as undefined behavior. Hence my statement that such an access does not violate the aliasing rule.

Comment: @HowardHinnant It would be great to clear up the language in the standard about how unions/aliasing/object lifetimes interact. Failing that, an explicit endorsement in the standard that "implementations must support type punning using this technique: ..." would make it possible to answer questions like this one without having reams and reams of discussion.

Comment: @casey i don't think that direction is ok either, based on my read of the C rationale document, because it gives a completely different rationale for that (and note that you not only have the union lvalue, but still the other member lvalue involved. So you still have the float vs int conflict).

Comment: In C++ unions for type punning lead to [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior/11996970#11996970). Considering that [memcpy provides a safe and efficient alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17790026/2436175), I see only danger in promoting the idea that unions are a good practical way for type punning.

Comment: @Casey: What's needed is to recognize that C is sometimes used for tasks that can be most efficiently performed via means such as type punning, and is sometimes used for tasks that don't.  Implementations that don't support such techniques may be able to process tasks that don't use them more efficiently than implementations that do, but implementations that do support such techniques may be able to process tasks that benefit from them more efficiently than those that don't.  The only way to write a rule that works well for both kinds of tasks is to recognize the existence of different...

Comment: ...abstraction models, and let programmers specify which models their code is compatible with.  Compromises like the broken "Effective Type" abstraction model in C, or the C++ "Dynamic Type" model for PODs, mean the languages don't work well for either kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

**Based on the answers here I made a modern "pseudo-cast" function for ease of application.**

**C99 version**
(while most compilers support it, theoretically could be undefined behavior in some)

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline T pseudo_cast(const U &x)
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value && std::is_trivially_copyable<U>::value, "pseudo_cast can't handle types which are not trivially copyable");

    union { U from; T to; } __x = {x};
    return __x.to;
}
```

**Universal versions**
(based on the accepted answer)

Cast types with the same size:

```
#include <cstring>

template <typename T, typename U>
inline T pseudo_cast(const U &x)
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value && std::is_trivially_copyable<U>::value, "pseudo_cast can't handle types which are not trivially copyable");
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(U), "pseudo_cast can't handle types with different size");
    
    T to;
    std::memcpy(&to, &x, sizeof(T));
    return to;
}
```

Cast types with any sizes:

```
#include <cstring>

template <typename T, typename U>
inline T pseudo_cast(const U &x)
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value && std::is_trivially_copyable<U>::value, "pseudo_cast can't handle types which are not trivially copyable");

    T to = T(0);
    std::memcpy(&to, &x, (sizeof(T) < sizeof(U)) ? sizeof(T) : sizeof(U));
    return to;
}
```

*Use it like:*

```
float f = 3.14f;
uint32_t u = pseudo_cast<uint32_t>(f);
```

**Update for C++20**

C++20 introduces `constexpr` [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) in header [`<bit>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) which is functionally equivalent for types with the same size. Nevertheless, the above versions are still useful if you want to implement this functionality yourself (supposed that `constexpr` is not required), or if you want to support types with different sizes.

Comment: C++20 has this as [`std::bit_cast<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) in `#include <bit>`

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, that makes this somewhat obsolete. However it is still useful if you want to implement that yourself - supposed that `constexpr` is not required. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only cast that will work here is `reinterpret_cast`.  (And
even then, at least one compiler will go out of its way to
ensure that it won't work.)

But what are you actually trying to do?  There's certainly
a better solution, that doesn't involve type punning.  There are
very, very few cases where type punning is appropriate, and they
all are in very, very low level code, things like serialization,
or implementing the C standard library (e.g. functions like
`modf`).  Otherwise (and maybe even in serialization), functions
like `ldexp` and `modf` will probably work better, and certainly
be more readable.