# Can unions be used to convert char arrays to float?

Tags: c++, arrays, type-punning

I was wondering whether or not is possible to use unions to get a float from a received char array. Let's say that I have defined the following struct

```
typedef union {
  float f;
  char c[4];
} my_unionFloat_t;
```

If I receive a char array encoding a float like this ( the numbers are made up)

```
data[4] = {32,45,56,88};
```

Can I do the following?

```
my_unionFloat_t c2f;

c2f.c[0] = data[0];
c2f.c[1] = data[1];
c2f.c[2] = data[2];
c2f.c[3] = data[3];

float result = c2f.f;
```

Comment: yes, if sender respects IEEE and endianness. but `memcpy(&the_float,the_string_data,sizeof(float))` achieves the same thing

Comment: Do note that using a unon for type punning in C++ is ilegal

Comment: that sounds like abusing the `union` feature though?

Comment: The proposed dup is not using a `char` array. You should make sure you use `unsigned char` (and not try to initialise 5 elements of a 4 element array).

Comment: @WeatherVane Whether it's an array or another type is irrelevant.

Comment: My understanding is that you can do this in c++ if you use an unsigned char array.

Comment: It looks like in C++, if you want to do this, [the best way is to use `memcpy`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17790026/1896169) as @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggested. You have to be careful, as in C++ it's really easy to break the strict-aliasing rules

Comment: @Bathsheba how can I do that in C++?

Comment: Note: no need to hard code 4.  Use `char c[sizeof (float)];`  BTW, it is better to use `unsigned char` - less complications.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre in your solution shouldn't I indicate the size of the_string_data?

Comment: @chux do you mean `char c[sizeof(float)]` in the definition of my union, don't you? Regarding to use `unsigned char` also in the same definition right?

Comment: @ndarkness Yes, `typedef union {
  float f;
  unsigned char uc[sizeof (float)];
} my_unionFloat_t;`  This is fine in C.  Notice commented links about additional C++ issues.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve that in C++ is to use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
unsigned char data[4] = {32,45,56,88};
float f = reinterpret_cast<const float&>(data);
const unsigned char* ch =  reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&f);
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    std::cout << +ch[i] << ' ';
std::cout << f << '\n';
```

Comment: Note that you want to be very careful; if you aren't casting to/from a `char *`, this is undefined behaviour due to strict-aliasing.

Comment: You forgot your `std::` on the second `cout`.

Comment: Thanks @JL2210. Don't you have enough reputation (yet) to directly edit?

Comment: @chtz Almost. Need 271 more.