# bitwise casting uint32_t to float in C/C++

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, type-punning

I'm receiving a buffer from a network which was converted to an array of 32-bit words.  I have one word which is defined as an IEEE-754 float by my interface document. I need to extract this word from the buffer.  It's tough to cast from one type to another without invoking a conversion.  The bits are already adhere to the IEEE-754 float standard, I don't want to re-arrange any bits.

My first try was to cast the address of the `uint32_t` to a `void*`, then convert the `void*` to a `float*`, then dereference as a `float`:

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
    return *((float*)((void*)(&f)));
}
```

> error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]

My second try was like this:

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
    union int_float{
        uint32_t i;
        float f;
    } tofloat;

    tofloat.i = f;
    return tofloat.f;
}
```

However, word on the street is that unions are totally unsafe.  It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

So I tried a more C++ approach:

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
  return *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&f);
}
```

> error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]

My next thought was "screw it. Why am I dealing with pointers anyways?" and just tried:

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<float>(f);
}
```

> error: invalid cast from type ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to type ‘float’

Is there a way to do the conversion without triggering the warning/error?  I'm compiling with g++ using `-Wall -Werror`.  I'd prefer to not touch compiler settings.

I tagged C because a c-solution is acceptable.

Comment: If you are compiling as C++, a C solution need not work. Different languages and all that. Or are you gonna compile that one function by a C compiler and link it in?

Comment: If a C-developer has a C-solution, I'd be happy to accept it because it'd probably work in C++ as well.  This is more a question of syntax than anything.

Comment: There's no way to do this without 'breaking the rules' or writing unsafe code. The union approach seems best to me.

Comment: Rubbish. Punning via union **is** the C solution. It's not undefined behavior, and will do exactly what you want so long as you don't end up with a trap representation. And yet in C++ it's undefined behavior. See the problem with double tagging?

Comment: What should happen when `sizeof(float) != sizeof(std::uint32_t)`?

Comment: `float ieee_float(uint32_t f) { void *p = &f; float fv = *(float*)p; return fv; }` but the `union` is cleaner `typedef union { float f; uint32_t v; } fu;` then `float ieee_float(uint32_t f) { fu.v = f; return fu.f; }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++20, you can use `std::bit_cast`:

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
    return std::bit_cast<float>(f);
}
```

In C++17 and before, *the right way*™ is:

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof f, "`float` has a weird size.");
    float ret;
    std::memcpy(&ret, &f, sizeof(float));
    return ret;
}
```

Both GCC and Clang at `-O1` and above generate the same assembly for this code and a naive `reinterpret_cast<float &>(f)` (but the latter is undefined behavior, and might not work in some scenarios).

Comment: @Zereges - All versions do a copy eventually. It returns by value after all.

Comment: Instead of using `4`, I would use `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone! Take this: [`[basic.val]/11.8`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.8).

Comment: @user694733 Or `sizeof f`.

Comment: In reinterpret_cast<float &>(f) please change the & to *

Comment: @Aminos This is not a typo. You can write `reinterpret_cast<T &>(x)` as a shorthand for `*reinterpret_cast<T *>(&x)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just checked this in cpp.sh and you are right. How long has this been around ? I really hate C++ because of all the hidden stuff.

Comment: @Aminos I think it was always there.

Comment: @Aminos It is 6) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: @Sebastian in 6) they don't talk about reinterpret_cast<T &> or I didn't understand the gibberish about lvalue.

Comment: @Aminos The whole page is about `reinterpret_cast` and 6) is about converting to *reference to T2*, which in total means `reinterpret_cast<T2&>(lvalue)` with `lvalue` of type `T1`.

Comment: for my own FYI https://godbolt.org/z/h3nxPbWTG

Answer (score 2):

There's no C/C++ language. They're different languages with different rules. The valid way in C is to use a union, but that's not allowed in C++. See

- [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848/995714)
- [Is type-punning through a union unspecified in C99, and has it become specified in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11639947/995714)

In older C++ standards you have to use `std::memcpy`. Even `reinterpret_cast` for type punning [invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53995657/995714), hence disallowed. In C++20 a new cast type called [`std::bit_cast`](http://std::bit_cast) was created exactly for this purpose

```
float ieee_float(uint32_t f)
{
  return std::bit_cast<float>(f);
}
```

See also:

- [What's a proper way of type-punning a float to an int and vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17789928/995714)
- [What is the modern, correct way to do type punning in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67636231/995714)

Comment: Some casts are allowed according to type casting rules.

Comment: @Sebastian which cast are you talking about? Nothing other than `bit_cast` is allowed to do type punning

Comment: See type aliasing section: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast Cast to `std::byte`, `char` and `unsigned char` (but not `signed char`, if not the same as `char` depending on platform) is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/3742943):

- Use the `union` solution: since C11 it is explicitly allowed (as said in the other answer).
- Instead of using an array of 32 bit words, use an array of 8 bit words (uint8_t), since `char` types can be aliased to any type.

Comment: The question was retagged to pure C++, so (1) doesn't apply. Also I highly doubt the (2) is well-defined...

Comment: IRC, any type can be aliased as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @YSC Yes, but IIRC not the other way around.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's it.

Comment: Using `union` for type punning is also allowed in C99. And even in C90 it was allowed if implementation supported it.