# This dereferencing pointer in C works fine, but it looks wrong

Tags: c, floating-point, dereference

This C code works fine (the compiler is GNU11). I'm sure it can improved since it gives a "dereferencing type-punned pointer" warning, but I don't know exactly how.

A uint8_t array contains 4 bytes that compose a floating point number. These 4 bytes are then stored in a uint32_t variable, and finally casted into a float variable:

```
uint8_t  buffer[];
uint32_t aux = 0;
float    value;

/*buffer contains the response from a sensor, containing a floating point number divided in 4 bytes*/

aux   = aux | ((buffer[3] << 24) | (buffer[4] << 16));
aux   = aux | ((buffer[5] << 8)  | (buffer[6]));
value = (float)*((float*)&aux);
```

Can this code present undefined behavior? I've read that I could use "union" get rid of the warning, but will will this get rid of the undefined behavior too?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as syntax goes, it's enough to write `value = *(float*)&aux;` Your parentheses are redundant, and there's no need to cast the result to `float`, because it's already a `float'.

Comment: `uint8_t  buffer[];` isn't valid C so yes the whole code is undefined behavior.

Comment: Other than that, it's UB as per a strict aliasing violation and that's also the reason for the warning. See the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The well defined method for type punning is using a `memcpy` between variables of the different types. I.e.

```
memcpy(&value, &aux, sizeof(float));
```

With optimization enabled and operating variables residing in automatic storage (i.e. regular function variables), this will translate into zero additional instructions, as the compiler will internally perform a single static assignment.

*EDIT:* Since C99 the other well defined method is using a `union` for type punning:

```
union {
    uint8_t  u8[sizeof(float)/sizeof(uint8_t)];
    uint32_t u32[sizeof(float)/sizeof(uint32_t)];
    float    flt;
} float_type_punner;
```

Comment: Since C99 using a `union` is fine for type-punning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified (not in C++, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803363/bitwise-casting-uint32-t-to-float-in-c-c)