# Conversion of float to integer in ARM based system

Tags: c++, gcc, arm64

I have the following piece of code called `main.cpp` that converts an IEE 754 32-bit hex value to float and then converts it into unsigned short.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int input_val = 0xc5dac022;
    float f;
    *((int*) &f) = input_val;
    unsigned short val = (unsigned short) f;
    cout <<"Val = 0x" << std::hex << val << endl;
}
```

I build and run the code using the following command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
./main
```

When I following code in my normal PC, I get the correct answer which is `0xe4a8`. But when I run the same code on an ARM processor, it gives an output of `0x0`.

Is this happening because I am building the code with normal gcc instead of aarch64? The code gives correct output for some other test cases on the ARM processor but gives an incorrect output for the given test value. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `*((int*) &f) = input_val; unsigned short val = (unsigned short) f;` - Yikes! Why on earth would you ever write something like that?

Comment: The cast is undefined behaviour because you broke the strict aliasing rule, use `std::memcpy(&f,&input_val,4);`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @Quimby Thanks, I will read about the strict aliasing rule. However I did make this change to my code, and my output is still incorrect. I still think this issue is because this code is being run on the ARM processor.

Comment: Perhaps your ARM machine is big endian?

Comment: @n.m. its little endian

Comment: Try `g++ main.cpp -o main -O2` on your PC, are you still getting the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/70867233/5282154  Use `std::bit_cast` for type punning w/o UB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your "type pun" via pointers violates the strict aliasing rule, as mentioned in comments.  You can fix that by switching to `memcpy`.

Next, the bit pattern `0xc5dac022` as an IEEE-754 single precision `float` corresponds to a value of about -7000, if my test is right.  This is truncated to  -7000, which, being negative, cannot be represented in an `unsigned short`.  As such, attempting to convert it to `unsigned short` has undefined behavior, per [7.3.10 p1] in the C++ standard (C++20 N4860).  Note this is different than the situation for trying to convert a signed or unsigned integer to `unsigned short`, which would have well-defined "wrapping" behavior.

So there is no "correct answer" here.  Printing 0 is a perfectly legal result, and is also logical in some sense, as 0 is the closest `unsigned short` value to -7000.  But it's also not surprising that the result would vary between platforms / compilers / optimization options, as this is common for UB.

---

There is actually a difference between ARM64 and x86-64 that explains why this is the particular behavior you see.

When compiling without  optimization, in both cases, gcc emits instructions to actually convert the `float` value to `unsigned short` at runtime.

ARM64 has a dedicated instruction `fcvtzu` that converts a `float` to a 32-bit `unsigned int`, so gcc emits that instruction, and then extracts the low 16 bits of the integer result.  The behavior of `fcvtzu` with a negative input is to output 0, and so that's the value that you get.

x86-64 doesn't have such an instruction.  The nearest thing is `cvttss2si` which converts a single-precision `float` to a **signed** 32-bit integer.  So gcc emits that instruction, then uses the low 16 bits of it as the `unsigned short` value.  This gives the right answer whenever the input `float` is in the range `[0, 65536)`, because all these values fit in the range of a 32-bit signed integer.  GCC doesn't care what it does in all other cases, because they are UB according to the C++ standard.  But it so happens that, since your value `-7000` does fit in `signed int`, then `cvstss2si` returns the signed integer -7000, which is `0xffffe4a8`.  Extracting the low 16 bits gives you the `0xe4a8` that you observed.

When optimizing, gcc on both platforms optimizes the value into a constant 0.  Which is also perfectly legal.

Comment: Based on your answer, doing this (unsigned short val = (short) f;) solved the issue.