# Creating constructor for a struct(union) in C++

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, arduino, unions

What is the best way to create a constructor for a struct(which has a union member, does it matter?) to convert `uint8_t` type into the struct?

Here is my example to  clarify more:

```
struct twoSixByte
{
    union {
        uint8_t fullByte;
        struct
        {
            uint8_t twoPart : 2;
            uint8_t sixPart : 6;
        } bits;
    };
};

uint32_t extractByte(twoSixByte mixedByte){
  return mixedByte.bits.twoPart * mixedByte.bits.sixPart;
}

uint8_t tnum = 182;
print(extractByte(tnum)); // must print 2 * 54 = 108
```

**P.S.**
Finding from comments & answers, type-punning for unions is not possible in C++.

The solutions given are a little bit complicated specially where there are lots of these structures in the code. There are even situations where a byte is divided into multiple bit parts(more than two). So without taking advantage of unions and instead using bitsets ans shifting bits adds a lot of burden to the code.

Instead, I managed for a much simpler solution. I just converted the type before passing it to the function. Here is the fixed code:

```
struct twoSixByte
    {
        union {
            uint8_t fullByte;
            struct
            {
                uint8_t twoPart : 2;
                uint8_t sixPart : 6;
            } bits;
        };
    };

    uint32_t extractByte(twoSixByte mixedByte){
      return mixedByte.bits.twoPart * mixedByte.bits.sixPart;
    }

    uint8_t tnum = 182;
    twoSixByte mixedType;
    mixedType.fullByte = tnum;
    print(extractByte(mixedByte)); // must print 2 * 54 = 108
```

Comment: How will you decide which part of the `union` is active?

Comment: Your problem statement is a little contradictory. You say you want to convert an `int` to a `twoSixByte` type, but in the example, you're converting a `uint8_t` into a `twoSixByte`, which is a different type.

Comment: yes, I want to convert uint8_t into twoSixByte. the value is passed by argument and needs a constructor. First two bits as twoPart and the remaining 6 bits as sixPart.

Comment: `print(...)`?? Is that your own function?

Comment: [Type punning in C++ is not ok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672839/1460794).

Comment: You could provide a constructor e.g. `twoSixByte(uint8_t value = 0): fullByte(value) { }`. Actually, it is not really allowed in C++ (but still works fine in our (similar) code - compiled in VS2013). ;-) Link: [SO: Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672839/7478597)

Comment: `182` in binary is `1011 0110`. Why do you think you should get `3` and `54` from that? It is `2` and `54`.

Comment: just fixed that Sahu. print is not a real function, just used it for maximum simplicity.

Comment: Hey, if you absolutely need type punning (e.g. from uint8_t to a struct full of bitfields), try the `memcpy` technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17790026/8120642

Comment: One issue with type punning and bitsets: the arrangement of bitset members in a struct are implementation defined.  `sixPart` ended up being the upper six bits for me, which is the opposite of what I'd expect. 
 It's the same whether I use the `union` or `memcpy` techniques.  It might or might not go the other way on your platform (I compiled using GCC 6.2.1 for x86, with -O0).

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is a pressing need for you to use a `union`, don't use it. Simplify your class to:

```
struct twoSixByte
{
   twoSixByte(uint8_t in) : twoPart((in & 0xC0) >> 6), sixPart(in & 0x3F) {}
   uint8_t twoPart : 2;
   uint8_t sixPart : 6;
};
```

If there is a need to get the full byte, you can use:

```
uint8_t fullByte(twoSixByte mixedByte)
{
   return ((mixedByte.twoPart << 6) | mixedByte.sixPart);
}
```

Comment: I have lots of structures like this. Unions really make it easy to extract full data bytes. Resources are limited in microcontrollers and It requires to save flags in bit level.

Comment: @Rev, My answer uses bit fields. It avoids use of a `union`.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the `union` and [type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672839/1460794) and use a struct with the relevant member function. Note that we don't need a constructor if the `struct` is regarded as an [aggregate to be initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
#include <cstdint>

struct twoSixByte {
    uint8_t fullByte; // no constructor needed, initializing as an aggregate
    uint32_t extractByte(){
        return ((fullByte & 0b1100'0000) >> 6) * (fullByte & 0b0011'1111);
    }
};


int main()
{
    twoSixByte tnum{182};
    auto test = tnum.extractByte(); // test == 2 * 54 == 108
}
```

Comment: Note that this is just as performant as using bitfields.  Accessing a bitfield compiles down to the same shifting and anding that's shown here.

Comment: This is really great but a little difficult to implement where the byte is separated into more than two parts. Imagine there are lots of such structures in code. Unions could really make it easier