# Unions in C - treating a float as an array of bytes

Tags: c

I have my union setup to read a 32 bit float value which is 32.0800018310 (binary = 100000.0001010001111011).

Now I want to display the contents of the float using the integer array which is 12 bytes (8 bits per byte).

However I get the following output:

```
Display:
236 
81 
0 
66
```

Shouldn't:

- `data_to_send[0]` return the first 8 bits of the float, which is 01111011 (decimal = 123)
- `data_to_send[1]` return the next 8 bits of the float which is 00010100 (decimal = 20)
- `data_to_send[2]` return the next 8 bits of the float which is 100000. (decimal = 32)
- `data_to_send[3]` return the next 8 bits of the float which is 0. (decimal = 0)

Also what happens to the `.` in the number? How do you display that?

```
union
{
  uint8_t  data_to_send[12];
  float    float_value;
} union_var;

union_var.float_value =  32.0800018310 

//display array
 USB.print("Display: ");
USB.printf("%d \n", union_var.data_to_send[0]);
USB.printf("%d \n", union_var.data_to_send[1]);
USB.printf("%d \n", union_var.data_to_send[2]);
USB.printf("%d \n", union_var.data_to_send[3]);
```

Comment: What makes you think it is `1000000001010001111011` in binary?

Comment: [Here's the IEEE-754 format for 32-bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32). The output in the question is correct for that format.

Comment: Why 12? Where do you get 12 from?

Comment: Consider using memcpy rather than union: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17790026/8120642

Answer (score 3):

How `float` values are stored depends on the architecture of your machine.

Nowadays, they are almost always stored in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format, which is quite different from the way you imagine.

Answer (score 1):

The floating point representation in Standard C is decomposed in 3 groups: sign, mantissa, exponent.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) you can see how to print it, reading it bit with bit and other informations about the floating point implemented by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

> float value which is 32.0800018310 (binary = 100000.0001010001111011).

You are confusing "Fixed-point number" representation with "floating-point number" representation.

The number 32.0800018310 do have the binary representation 00000000.0100000.00010100.01111011 **if stored as a fixed-point number with scaling factor 2^16**

That is:

```
2^16 is 65536

00000000.0100000.00010100.01111011 as normal binary number is  2102395

and

2102395 / 65536 is 32.0800018310
```

So as a fixed-point number with scaling factor 2^16 your binary representation is correct but ...

Computers don't store floating point as fixed-point numbers. The common way is to use IEEE 754 format.

So when you print your float in binary you'll see the binary representation for IEEE 754 instead of the values you expected.

Fixed-point format is not part of the C standard but there are a number of C fixed-point libraries that can be downloaded from the net if you want to play with fixed-point math.