# Safe and Efficient Type Punning in C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-punning

```
uint32_t Seed() {
    uint64_t seed = GetSomeReasonable64BitIntegerSeed();
    return *(uint32_t*)&seed ^ *((uint32_t*)&seed + 1);
}
```

Above is not real code, but that's basically what the real code does. I got a warning from g++ that it violates strict aliasing, googled it, and okay I want to fix it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346622/opinions-on-type-punning-in-c) question, but it doesn't give a clear solution other than using `memcpy`, or relying on undefined but practically-no-problem behaviour, that is to access an unset member of a union.

The current options I can think of are,

1. Use `memcpy`.
2. Use a `union` and compile this part as C, where the language standard allows type punning via unions.

Comment: safe type punning can be done with [`std::bit_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832038/995714). But this is actually an XY problem that doesn't need type punning at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bit-wise arithmetic is well defined and perhaps more efficient. For this example:

```
return seed ^ (seed >> 32);
```